# Is there any name for $f(x) = xa^x$?

Tags: terminology, graphing-functions

We call $a^x$ as an exponential function. Many things like compound interest, bacteria growth etc follow this model of $ba^x$.

It's behaviour is $f(x)$ and all order derivatives will keep on increasing x increases and at any point proportional to $a^x$. To put it in another way, it will be a straight line with slope $b$ in a logarithmic scale.

Now let's take this function $f(x) = xa^x$. This won't be  a straight line in log scale. It will concaving upward.

Is there any name for this particular curve?

Comment: Is there any name for $f(x)=x^2a^x$? Or $f(x)=x^3a^x$? It don't see a particular reason why you only ask for $xa^x$. Probably there are not enough names for all the functions we can think of.

Comment: It is probably called the inverse product log, or the inverse of the Lambert W function. [See here for more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: I would call it Jimmy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most apt name for such a function would be a "**product exponential**", as its famous inverse is sometimes called a *product logarithm.*